# How to show Facebook Profile Picture after logged in?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add facebook login in an android app. Successfully done that following this tutorial https://www.studytutorial.in/android-facebook-integration-and-login-tutorial. It contains two activity MainActivity, UserProfileActivity. MainActivity is App launcher, with login Button. After correct credentials the UserProfileActivity called upon via intent, it has its own layout xml, so it shows User Profile Pic, name and email.

After pressing back button, return to MainActivity--- Resulting view is the loginButton's text changed to logout button. After pressing logout button, logout performs, but when login again, it says "You are previously logged in with some_user_name. With continue and cancel button.

So my question is, how to clear previous login details. And One more thing, how to show the profile picture as ImageView of MainActivity(just above loginButton)?

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getUserDetails(loginResult);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("LOGIN_CANCEL", "Cancel");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("LOGIN_ERROR", "Error");
        }
    });
}
protected void getUserDetails(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
         new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject json_object, GraphResponse response) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userProfile", json_object.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
    permission_param.putString("fields", "id, name, email, picture.width(120).height(120)");
    data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
    data_request.executeAsync();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here is my UserProfileActivity

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
JSONObject response, profile_pic_data, profile_pic_url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String jsondata = intent.getStringExtra("userProfile");
    Log.w("Jsondata", jsondata);
    ImageView user_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    TextView user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
    TextView user_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    try {
        response = new JSONObject(jsondata);
        user_email.setText(response.get("email").toString());
        user_name.setText(response.get("name").toString());
        profile_pic_data = new JSONObject(response.get("picture").toString());
        profile_pic_url = new JSONObject(profile_pic_data.getString("data"));
        Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic_url.getString("url")).into(user_picture);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `ProfilePictureView`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the profile pic using ID with external url like this

```
String       sfacebookId = json_object.getString("id");
try {
URL image_url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + sfacebookId + "/picture?type=large");
user_image = image_url.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

replace with

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");
```

and you get it when you did

```
profile_pic_data = new JSONObject(response.get("picture").toString());
```

which represents the url of the image.